# How do I control the page to which a user is directed after logging in using AAD B2C in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, azure-ad-b2c, webassembly, azure-ad-msal, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a hosted WASM website using Azure's AAD B2C for user authentication and authorization.  The root of the website is a simple landing page that presents the user with a button that takes the user to the Authorization page, which is identical to the default one created according to the tutorial at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-5.0

I would like the user to be redirected to a specific page once they complete the login procedure- not back to the landing page (and not to a page they were on with an [authorize] tag that they weren't authorized to access).  I have tried setting returnUrl to the url of the page I want the user to be directed to after login ( Navigation.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl=http://localhost:5000/Start"); ), but we are still directed back to the root page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have an Authentication component, which has in it a RemoteAuthenticatorView component, and that has an OnLogInSucceeded parameter which you can use to register a method to be called when the user logs in - in this method you can set the `state.ReturnUrl` to redirect wherever you like, e.g. Counter as shown below:

#### Authentication.razor

```cs
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" OnLogInSucceeded="LoginSuccessHandler" />

@code{
 [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }
 [Inject] public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

 void LoginSuccessHandler(RemoteAuthenticationState state)
 {
  state.ReturnUrl = "Counter";
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works perfectly.
Do you know where I could have found the documentation that would have explained this?  I could not find any reference to this on any of the documentation I looked at concerning securing a .NET Core app.

Comment: Not good documentation, no - there is the component page in docs, but it doesn't explain anything about using the component - but that pointed me to the OnLogInSucceeded and from there it was just a matter of inspecting the RemoteAuthenticationState to see what options were available and that led to the ReturnUrl.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.authentication.remoteauthenticationstate.returnurl?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Authentication_RemoteAuthenticationState_ReturnUrl

Comment: This works in web assembly, how about server-side?